# How to reorder a vectorized tensor in R?

Tags: r

For example, consider a vectorized dim R*S*T tensor

```
A <- (a111,a112,a113,...a11T,a121,...a1ST..,a311,...,aRST)
```

How can I reorder it to obtain

```
(a_111,a_211,...,a_R11,a_112,a_212,...,a_RST)
```

---

One way is to convert A to an array

```
Arr <- array(A,dim = (R,S,T))
```

and then vectorize it in a different way. I'm not sure how to do this or whether it is efficient.

`c(Arr)` does not allow specifying the axis to expand.

`expand.grid()` seems not helpful either, since the first factors always vary the fastest.

Comment: I think what you are doing is okay; I am not aware of a way to directly set the dimensions of the original vector A as you want. But to reshape Arr you can use `aperm` e.g. `c(aperm(Arr, c(3, 1, 2)))`

Comment: ... you could probably avoid a copy by using `dim(A) = c(R, S, T)`, as Allan does below, rather than calling `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take as an example the following vector which helpfully contains integers in the form `RST` so that we can track them. We will assume a 3 x 3 x 3 array:

```r
A <- c(111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133,
       211, 212, 213, 221, 222, 223, 231, 232, 233,
       311, 312, 313, 321, 322, 323, 331, 332, 333)
```

All we need to do is specify the dimensions of the original:

```r
dim_A <- c(3, 3, 3)
```

And we can get the reordered array as a vector like this:

```r
c(t(apply(array(A, dim = dim_A), 3, \(x) x)))
#>  [1] 111 211 311 112 212 312 113 213 313 121 221 321 122 222 322 123 223 323 131
#> [20] 231 331 132 232 332 133 233 333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>